# University Question including for loops and lists

Tags: python, loops

the question is asking me to do this In a small highland village, everyone has the surname McIntosh, McGregor, McDonald or McKenzie.
Everyone is called Angus, Hamish, Morag or Mhairi
No two people have the same name.
Create a program to compile a list of the inhabitants of the village.

It makes use of lists and loops but I don't know how to do it, this is what i have so far

```
surnames = ["Mcintosh", "McGregor", "McDonald", "Mckenzie"]
forenames = ["Angus", "Hamish", "Morag", "Mhairi"]

for forenames in forenames:
    for surnames in surnames:
        print forenames
```

Comment: What is the problem with your code? What happens when you run it and what did you expect to happen instead? Any errors? See [ask]

Comment: You probably want to change the variable after the `for` to not be the same as the lists, and then print both first and last name

Comment: Your question indicates you have misunderstood how to use loops in Python. A tutorial (or talking with your instructor) would be more helpful than Stack Overflow. Unlike python 2, python 3 doesn't contain a `print` statement, only a `print(...)` function. Also you want to print their _full_ name, so why print just the first name?

Comment: As stated, this is impossible to answer; there could be a set as small as 4 people that satisfy the requirement, and there are many such sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea with doing a nested loop, but you need to use a different variable name for the `for var in iterable` part, and you need to print the variables from both loops.

```
>>> surnames = ["Mcintosh", "McGregor", "McDonald", "Mckenzie"]
>>> forenames = ["Angus", "Hamish", "Morag", "Mhairi"]
>>> for fore in forenames:
...     for sur in surnames:
...         print(fore, sur)
...
Angus Mcintosh
Angus McGregor
Angus McDonald
Angus Mckenzie
Hamish Mcintosh
Hamish McGregor
Hamish McDonald
Hamish Mckenzie
Morag Mcintosh
Morag McGregor
Morag McDonald
Morag Mckenzie
Mhairi Mcintosh
Mhairi McGregor
Mhairi McDonald
Mhairi Mckenzie
```

Note that e.g. `surnames` is the list of all the surnames, and `for sur in surnames` assigns *each individual surname* to the variable `sur`.

Answer (score 1):

You have a great start, but I think you need more an explanation of what is happening. The first loop will be picking the forename. The second loop will be choosing the last name.

To understand this more clearly here is an example

```
first = [1, 2, 3, 4]
second = [1, 2, 3, 4]

for i in first:
    for k in second:
        print(i, k)
```

OUTPUT:

```
1 1
1 2
1 3
1 4
2 1
2 2
2 3
2 4
3 1
3 2
3 3
3 4
4 1
4 2
4 3
4 4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
surnames = ["Mcintosh", "McGregor", "McDonald", "Mckenzie"]
forenames = ["Angus", "Hamish", "Morag", "Mhairi"]


print({f"{i} {j}"for j in forenames for i in surnames})

# {'Mhairi Mcintosh', 'Morag Mckenzie', 'Mhairi Mckenzie', 'Mhairi McDonald', 'Angus McGregor', 'Morag McGregor', 'Angus Mckenzie', 'Hamish Mckenzie', 'Angus Mcintosh', 'Morag McDonald', 'Angus McDonald', 'Hamish McGregor', 'Morag Mcintosh', 'Hamish Mcintosh', 'Mhairi McGregor', 'Hamish McDonald'}
```